# drop down only shows single value i have multiple value in my database

Tags: php, mysql

This my code, using tables `upload-data`,`login`,`paper`

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head><body>
    <table border="3"><tr>
    <th>Paper id</th>
    <th>Paper Name</th>
    <th>Reviewer Name</th>
    <th>Paper Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("conferencedb");
            $qry="select paperid,papername from paper";
            $rs=mysql_query($qry);
            
            $qry1="select (`username`) from login where type='reviewer'";
            $rs1=mysql_query($qry1);
            
            
            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
            {
                if($row1=mysql_fetch_row($rs1))
                {
            
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
                    echo "<td><select name='type'>
```

only single option can fetch from the database

```
                        <option value='$row1[0]'>$row1[0]</option>
                    </select></td>";
                    echo "<td>Pending</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                } 
            }
    ?>
    
    
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </body>
    </html>
```

above code is working ,but it retrieve only single row from the database: `$row1[0];`
The current output window...i just marked area using
paint.

Comment: Instead of if($row1=mysql_fetch_row($rs1)) use  while($row1=mysql_fetch_row($rs1))

Comment: paperid and papername are same for all the tables when i adding  the above code..no change in the drop down list

Comment: How many record is comes in $row and $row1?

Comment: in dropdown i want to list the reviewer names it is more than two in $row1 more than 3 records and  $row contain maximum of 10

Comment: Why are taking while inside if?

Comment: So no one's going to mention the elephant in the room?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row` fetches `1` row at a time.

So if you want to get multiple rows use

```
while($row1=mysql_fetch_row($rs1))
```

instead of

```
if($row1=mysql_fetch_row($rs1))
```

OR

> **EDIT FOR USING MYSQLi**

If you could switch to MySQLi you could use:

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysqli_select_db("conferencedb");
            $qry="select paperid,papername from paper";
            $rs=mysqli_query($qry);

            $qry1="select (`username`) from login where type='reviewer'";
            $rs1=mysqli_query($qry1);


            while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($rs))
            {
               if($row1= mysqli_fetch_all ($rs1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
                    echo "<td><select name='type'>
```

`mysqli_fetch_all` will fetch all the result rows of the `SELECT` statement as an array of rows.

> EDIT FOR MULTIPLE OPTIONS INSIDE SELECT

Also

```
 echo "<td><select name='type'> 
    <option value='$row1[0]'>$row1[0]</option>
</select></td>";
```

will always give you one option tag.

```
echo "<td><select name='type'>";
foreach($_row1 in $row1){
        echo "<option value='$_row1[0]'>$_row1[0]</option>";
     }
        echo "</select></td>";
        echo "<td>Pending</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } 
   }
  ?>


    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\conference\assignforrev.php on line 29

Comment: apply the above code will get an error..Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: Connection was made using mysql....made it MySQLi, try it now...if it still gives the error try `$con-
>mysqli_select_db("conferencedb");` instead of `mysqli_select_db("conferencedb");`

Comment: got the correct answer. used while inside while.. while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs)){$qry="select username from login where type='reviewer'";
 $result =mysql_query($qry);
 echo "<td><select name=dropdown>";
 while($r= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<option value=".$r[0].">".$r[0]."</option>";
 }

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it? You are using two arrays in one loop. So I doing like this

And, I don't know whther we can do like this $row[0]['column'],$row[1]['column']???

```
       while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
        {
        if($row1=mysql_fetch_row($rs1))
        {
```

to only

```
       $count=0;
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
          echo $paperid=mysql_result($rs,$count,'paperid');
          echo $papername=mysql_result($rs,$count,'papername');
          echo $username=mysql_result($rs1,$count,'username');               
          $count=$count+1;
```